# isset doesn't work with variable with apostrophe

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the exact part of the code that doesn't work

```
if(isset($_GET['Champion'])){
        $championget = trim(urldecode($_GET['Champion']));
        echo $championget;
        $championexists = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM champions where Champion = ?");
        $championexists->bind_param('s', $championget);
        $championexists->execute();
        $championexistsresult = $championexists->get_result();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($championexistsresult)==0){
            echo 'Champion doesn\'t exist'; 
            exit;
        }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($championexistsresult)>=1)
            {
                //Continue here
                include('php/champion.php');
                exit;
            }

    }
```

Works fine with regular names like http://localhost/leaguenotes/Cassiopeia 
but i have names that have ' in them that is why i encoded them so they look like this http://localhost/leaguenotes/Cho%27Gath but this redirects me to folder index

Here is also htaccess that might be at fault

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
ErrorDocument 403 /

Options ALL -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9/.]+)$ index.php?Patch_No=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9/.]+)&([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?Patch_No=$1&tab=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^patches php/patches.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?Champion=$1 [NC,L]
```

It just seems like because of %27 my code doesn't interpert this as a variable

Comment: % won't match your regex patterns as it's not in the group.

Comment: is there an easy way to add % into pattern?

Comment: Sure, allow it. e.g. `^([0-9a-zA-Z_%-]+)$` EDIT: Make sure the hyphen is last, or escaped.

Comment: Just tried that i casues Internal Server Error for some reason

Comment: Did you try my updated comment, or the original one?

Comment: Yeah just now well the site work but still RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_%-]+)$ index.php?Champion=$1 [NC,L] kicks me out to index folder like it doesn't notice the variable

Answer (score 2):

Anything URL encoded (e.g. `%27`) get decoded before the URI is sent through the rewrite rules, that means you can't try to match against `%27`, but to what that decodes to.

So instead of the regex:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z_-]
```

you need to include the apostrophe

```
['0-9a-zA-Z_-]
```

Comment: Does that mean if you were actually wanting to match something that had `%27`, or other entity, but was intended as a literal, you could see odd behaviour?

Comment: one more thing how can I deal with space in name?

Comment: @JonStirling Not sure I understand your question. If you wanted to match against `%27` (the encoded URL would look like `%2527` because the `%` gets encoded) you need to escape the `%`.

Comment: @Higeath to deal with a space, just add a space in the square brackets but you need to escape it: `['0-9a-zA-Z\ _-]`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use them. Stick purely to A-Za-z0-9 and _ . (There are some other characters you can use, but they are reserved and have special meaning).

Comment: what do you mean that i shouldn't use apostrophe? it is required it's a part of a name of that certain champion and that is why i use urlencode and urldecode

Comment: try with this [0-9a-zA-Z_-'] in your .htaccess